# Get a breakline on every line on javascript without using "<br>"

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

Is there a way to get a breakline in Javascript? just like `println` in Java without using `< br>` after every statement. I tried `document.writeln` because I am using it in HTML.However, it only gives a space not a breakline. Using `< br>` is quite redundant as I need to write it every time and `writeln` is not giving me what I want. I googled it a lot but couldn't find any helpful solution. The following is my code, if somebody can help, it would be appreciated.

```
var list = [1, 3, 5, 7];
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            document.writeln(list[i]);
        }
```

Comment: It's not redundant, it's necessary. That's just how HTML works. `document.writeln(list[i] + '<br>');`

Comment: However what if I need to print like a lot of strings? I will have to write "<br>" on every statement. So, I was just wondering if there is a way to do it. Don't know what got me that downvote

Comment: Can you better describe your end goal? Using `document.write` is not good practice and can even fail in certain headers are set. If you just want to see the code you can always use `console.log(list[i])` but that shows in the developer console. If you want to output into the HTML there are many better ways then what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question is very pertinent, besides Reticent, but would be more interesting if you googled a little before asking it - cause are plenty of this kind of question done before you - even here at SO. Along with this, downvoting is getting viral here, lazy people even don't have the work to say nothing (people are Reticent, you're right), they just click down and rest in peace. Poor humanity :D

Comment: Yeah, I need to output into HTML. I know about "console.log", thank you. So, can you please tell me the ways you are talking about.

Comment: Modern web development would use something like Vue/React/Angular and their respective templating systems. Raw `document.write` is rarely appropriate nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in  `<pre>` tag or use css `white-space` to fit your needs

```html
<pre>
<script>
var list = [1, 3, 5, 7];
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    document.writeln(list[i]);
}
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: This can come with fairly substantial styling/layout side-effects.

Comment: @ceejayoz agree.. not clear what OP's use case really is

Comment: layout problem occurred though @ charlietfl

Comment: Create a helper function then

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [1, 3, 5, 7];
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        document.writeln(list[i] + "<br>");
```

The above code is with the line break.
Without the line break I would use:

```
var list = [1, 3, 5, 7];
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    document.writeln("<span>" + list[i] + "</span>");
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this will be the easiest way.

Comment: Ryan I think I have made it clear, I don't want to use "<br>" statement because if I have to print a lot of strings it will be redundant as I have to write it every time.